# How to use filter to dynamic shortcodes?

Tags: wordpress, filter, shortcode

I just create shortcodes like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'demo1', 'demo1_init' ) );
add_shortcode( 'demo2', 'demo2_init' ) );

function demo1_init() {
   // Shortcode Def. here...
}

function demo2_init() {
   // Shortcode Def. here...
}
```

How can I use filters to create these shortcodes dynamically? Something like this. E.g.

```
 $a = array(
        "demo1"       =>  "demo1_init",
        "demo2"       =>  "demo2_init",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get the job done

```
function demo1_init() {
    // Shortcode Def. here...
    return "demo1";
}

function demo2_init() {
    // Shortcode Def. here...
    return "demo2";
}

function register_shortcodes() {

    $shortcodes = array(
        "demo1"   =>  "demo1_init",
        "demo2"   =>  "demo2_init",
    );

    foreach($shortcodes as $shortcode => $func) {       
        add_shortcode($shortcode, $func);
    }

}
add_action( "init", "register_shortcodes" );
```